# What is the right way to create a small "shortcuts driven" desktop application in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, ubuntu-22.04, systemctl

I want to create a small "shortcuts driven" desktop application in Ubuntu. Essentially my application will listen for three key combinations and run some code (to modify wayland compositor config) based on the key combo. What is the right way to write the driver part of such an application (the logic that listens to key combos in the background). It would be ideal to be able to install it in any linux system (I know the compositor incompatibility but that I can take care of).

Here is what I have discovered from my research:
systemctl - I can run a service in the background that listens for the shortcuts and takes appropriate action. Won't this be too heavy? Is this a right way to do the thing? Is there anything better you can point me to?